# angular js using $http factory from wamp server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Learning angular js

This is my code -

Note url in facory code

**factory**

```
carPriceApp.factory('ergastAPIservice', function($http) {

    var ergastAPI = {};

    ergastAPI.getDrivers = function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'JSONP', 
        url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
          /*url: 'http://localhost/carprices2/api/eger.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'*/
      });
    }

    return ergastAPI;
  });
```

**controller**

```
carPriceApp.controller('brand', function($scope){

}).controller('model', function($scope, ergastAPIservice) {
    $scope.nameFilter = null;
    $scope.driversList = [];

    ergastAPIservice.getDrivers().success(function (response) {
        //Dig into the responde to get the relevant data
        $scope.driversList = response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
    });
  });
```

This code is fine

**Problem**

Not working when i change the url path `local` instead of `online`

*I just download api file and put it as local file (windows wamp sever) Then url call* `url: 'http://localhost/carprices2/api/eger.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

I am learning Angular JS - Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show the contents of the file you save locally (`eger.js`). Also, define "_not working_." What should happen, what does happen, what errors do you see?

Comment: You will get content of the file  I posted the online  api url

Comment: That is not how SO is intended to work...show all pertinent code and content. Remote sources can go away (or may not be trusted...).

Comment: Does the address in your browser start with `http://localhost/`? Can you directly load `http://localhost/carprices2/api/eger.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` in your browser and see expected output?

Comment: Yes -Its  directly loaded http://localhost/carprices2/api/eger.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

Comment: Back to my original comment, then-- please define, "_not working_". Do you get any errors? Do the developer tools show the request being made successfully?

Comment: I coudnt see any error in chrome console but I can see "ReferenceError: JSON_CALLBACK is not defined"  in mozilla firebugg

Comment: angular will convert `JSON_CALLBACK` to something else I think...check dev tools for actual url used in request. I don't think you can hard code your file and need to use a server script to handle the GET param `callback`